# The path for Categories in the main menu and Footer Menu is different

Tags: magento-1.7, url, menu

This is the path for About us in main menu

`http://name/index.php/about.html`

For Same About Us in the footer menu is

```
http://name/index.php/about.html%EF%BF%BD%20title=
```

The link for the Categories in the footer menu leads to page not found error.

Pls help

Answer (score 1):

Open admin->cms->static blocks, edit "Footer Links" static block. Hide editor and review html content. There might be some typo mistakes related to quote. My footer links looks like these:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="{{store direct_url="about-magento-demo-store"}}">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store direct_url="customer-service"}}">Customer Service</a></li>
<li class="last privacy"><a href="{{store direct_url="privacy-policy-cookie-restriction-mode"}}">Privacy Policy</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: There is no footer links under cms->Static Blocks

Answer (score 0):

there should be wrong encoding or and it doesnt work. Try to save it as utf-8 or what is the rest of your encoding is.

open with notepad and chose utf-8.